# How to pass specific string to get the specific value from database android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have three columns where trailer_number and trailer_id are strings

```
id   trailer_number  trailder_id
1       trailer1       766
2       trailer2       899
3       trailer3       577
```

Now if I pass the trailer_number, how to get the specific trailer_id.
Say for eg: trailer1 if i pass, how to return the string "766"?

I can do only if that specific string is exist or not but I am cluless how to pass to get the specific id.

```
public boolean isExist(String strTrailerNumber) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE TRAILER_NUMBER = '" + strTrailerNumber + "'", null);
        boolean exist = (cur.getCount() > 0);
        cur.close();
        db.close();
        return exist;

    }
```

Comment: "SELECT trailder_id FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE TRAILER_NUMBER = '" + strTrailerNumber + "'", null)

Answer (score 0):

Tryout as below :

```
 String query = "SELECT trailder_id FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TRAILER_NUMBER =" + strTrailerNumber ;
        Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 while (cursor.isAfterLast() != true) {
                   string trailder_id =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("trailder_id")));
                  }
        }
```

There might be some syntax error in Query, change it. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

use the query

```
"SELECT trailder_id FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE TRAILER_NUMBER = '" + strTrailerNumber + "'"
```

and use

```
cursor.moveToFirst()
String trailer_id = cursor.getString(0)
```

to get the trailder_id